# Ruby performance in .each loops

Tags: ruby, loops

Consider the following two peices of ruby code

### Example 1

```
name = user.first_name
round_number = rounds.count
users.each do |u|
  puts "#{name} beat #{u.first_name} in round #{round_number}"
end
```

### Example 2

```
users.each do |u|
  puts "#{user.first_name} beat #{u.first_name} in #{rounds.count}"
end
```

For both pieces of code imagine

```
#user.rb
def first_name
  name.split.first
end
```

So in a classical analysis of algorithms, the first piece of code would be more efficient, however in most modern compiled languages, modern compilers would optimize the second piece of code to make it look like the first, eliminating the need to optimize code in such maner.

Will ruby optimize or cache values for this code before execution? Should my ruby code look like example 1 or example 2?

Comment: Did you try benchmarking it? Probably ruby implementation dependant anyway, but  I don't think that ruby would do that for you

Comment: I was going to benchmark it, but figured someone might just know, and this question would sever as a good way of documenting that test.

Comment: Benchmarking the two examples would have taken you a few minutes and would have given you a concrete answer.

Comment: Benchmarking the two examples would have taken you a few minutes and would have given you a concrete answer in the same time it took you to ask. Try it and you'll see if the difference is subtle and not worth bothering with, or extreme and worth using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example 1 will run faster, as `first_name()` is only called once, and it's value stored in the variable.

In Example 2 Ruby will not memoize this value automatically, since the value could have changed between iterations for the `each()` loop.

Therefor expensive-to-calculate methods should be explicitly memoized if they are expected to be used more than once without the return value changing.

Making use of Ruby's [Benchmark Module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) can be useful when making decisions like this. It will likely only be worth memoizing if there are a lot of values in `users`, or if `first_name()` is expensive to calculate.

Answer (score 2):

A compiler can only perform this optimization if it can prove that the method has no side effects. This is even more difficult in Ruby than most languages, as everything is mutable and can be overridden at runtime. Whether it happens or not is implementation dependent, but since it's hard to do in Ruby, most do not. I actually don't know of any that do at the time of this posting.

Comment: Like so many interesting compiler optimizations, proving that a method has no side-effects is equivalent to solving the Halting Problem in the general case.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Yep. It is doable in specific cases in some languages, though. For example, compilers can very often prove that accessors do not produce side effects, as in the example the OP offered. If all a function does is read some memory and return the value without ever writing outside the stack or calling functions that are not known to be pure, it really can't cause side effects.